# C++ Is there a way to initialize a class using different types for the same argument?

Tags: c++, class, initializer

I have a class Obj  with zero or two arguments.

- No arguments
- First arg is always a std::string name.
- Second arg it shoud be of three different class types.

I would something like this:

```
class Sphere{
    public:
    int radius=1;
    int a;
};
class Plane{
    public:
    int a=11;
    int b=12;
    int c=13;
};
class Light{
    public:
    int pos=555;
    int a;
};
class Obj{
    public:
    std::string name;
    Sphere s;
    Light l;
    Plane p;
    int type;
    bool defined;
    
    //with no arguments
    Obj(){
       defined=false;
       type=0;
    }
    //Type Sphere as second arg
    Obj(std::string name,Sphere _s){
       defined=true;
       type=1;
       s=_s;
    }
    //Or Type Light as second arg
    Obj(std::string name,Light _l){
       defined=true;
       type=2;
       l=_l;
    }
    //Or Type Plane as second arg
    Obj(std::string name,Plane _p){
       defined=true;
       type=3;
       p=_p;
    }

};
```

The meaning should be the ability to put several objects of different types in the same array typed in only one way.

Is it possible in some way ? Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT:**

(C++11)

Knowing that it compiles is already a great start. Thanks.

> The above example only works if the Sphere, Plane, Light classes have
> no arguments.

Adding the same argument number to the Sphere, Plane, Light classes also fails. The same if the 3 classes have different number of arguments.

```
#include <iostream>

class Sphere{
    public:
    int radius=1;
    int a;
    Sphere( int _a ){
        a=_a;        
    }
};
class Plane{
    public:
    int a=11;
    int b=12;
    int c=13;

    Plane( int _a ){
        a=_a;        
    }

    //Plane(int _a,int _b,int _c){
    //    a=_a;b=_b;c=_c;
    //}
};
class Light{
    public:
    int pos=555;
    int a;
    Light(int _a){
        a=_a;        
    }
};


class Obj{
    public:
    std::string name;
    Sphere s;
    Light l;
    Plane p;
    int type;
    bool defined;
    
    //with no arguments
    Obj(){
       defined=false;
       type=0;
    }
    //Type Sphere as second arg
    Obj(std::string _name,Sphere _s){
       name=_name;
       defined=true;
       type=1;
       s=_s;
    }
    //Or Type Light as second arg
    Obj(std::string _name,Light _l){
       name=_name;
       defined=true;
       type=2;
       l=_l;
    }
    //Or Type Plane as second arg
    Obj(std::string _name,Plane _p){
       name = _name;
       defined=true;
       type=3;
       p=_p;
    }
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int a=111; 
    int b=222; 
    int c=333;
    
    Obj sph1=Obj("sphere1",Sphere(a));
    Obj sph2=Obj("sphere2",Sphere(b));
    Obj lig1=Obj("Light1", Light(c));
    Obj lig2=Obj("Light2", Light(c));
    //Obj pla1=Obj("Plane1", Plane(a,b,c));
    //Obj pla2=Obj("Plane2", Plane(c,b,a));
    
    cout<<"sp1 name:"  << sph1.name << endl;
    cout<<"sp1 radius:"<< sph1.s.radius << endl;
    
    //cout<<"pla1 name:" << pla1.name << endl;
    //cout<<"pla1 p1:"   << pla1.p.p1 << endl;
    //cout<<"pla2 name:" << pla1.name << endl;
    //cout<<"pla2 p1:"   << pla1.p.p1 << endl;
  
    cout<<"Hello"<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here the compiler error:

```
Error:
vt.cpp: In constructor ‘Obj::Obj()’:
vt.cpp:64:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘Sphere::Sphere()’
     Obj(){
          ^
vt.cpp:22:5: note: candidate: Sphere::Sphere(int)
     Sphere( int _a ){
     ^~~~~~
vt.cpp:22:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
vt.cpp:18:7: note: candidate: constexpr Sphere::Sphere(const Sphere&)
 class Sphere{
       ^~~~~~
```

Comment: If an "object" can only be one of these three things, it makes no sense that it stores an instance of all three things.  It seems like you're trying to make some kind of variant, but actually what you should probably be doing is using polymorphism to create `Sphere`, `Light`, and `Plane` objects that are all subclasses of `Obj`.

Comment: All that you did wrong was misspelled `std::string` as `std:string`. Once I fixed that, the code compiles and works. It may not be the most efficient, but it does work. Did it not work for you?

Comment: You could also use a `std::variant<Sphere, Light, Plane>` as a member of your `Obj`

Comment: Your later error is because `Plane` doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: If you don't want to rely on C++17, you can always go "old school" and use the [Factory pattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/design-patterns-set-2-factory-method/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++17 solution for this is `std::variant`, although based on `defined` you probably want to wrap it in an `std::optional`.

```
class Obj{
    public:
    std::string name;
    using Value = std::variant<Sphere, Light, Plane>;
    std::optional<Value> v;
    
    //with no arguments
    Obj() = default;

    //Type Sphere as second arg
    Obj(std::string name,Sphere _s) : v{std::make_optional<Value>(_s)} { }
    // ...
};
```

`std::variant` keeps track of which type is stored for you, and you don't have to pay for the overhead of all three instances.  `std::optional` handles the `defined` part for you.

You could be a bit slicker by templating the constructor and passing the second argument along blindly.

```
    template <typename T>
    Obj(std::string name, T _v) : v{std::make_optional<Value>(_v)} { }
```

Comment: Potentially, [`std::monostate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/monostate) can be used in `std::variant` instead of `std::optional`.